# Multiple Bluetooth Speakers

Tags: itunes, audio, bluetooth, sharing, speakers

1) Is it possible to output the audio over a2dp to multiple speakers simultaneously?
2) Is it possible to change the audio output to A2DP speakers directly from iTunes or do I have to change the system preferences every time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1) I think it's dependand on the speaker set you're using, but I don't think so.

2) No, you can change your audio output in a simpler way:

1. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> resp. <kbd>Option</kbd>
2. Click on the volume icon
3. Select your input/output sources

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using Audio MIDI Setup, it's in the Utilities folder.

1. From the list of devices on the left, just click on the plus icon at
   the bottom left of the list.
2. Select "Create multi-output device"
3. Add the different bluetooth gadgets to this new "device"

To rename the device, right-click on it once it's in the list and call it something memorable.